# Jakarta @Nonnull does not cause validation error in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-validation

I'm studying validation in Spring and jakarta. I created rest simple controller:

```
@RestController
class EmailController {

    @PostMapping(path = ["/email"])
    fun post(
        @RequestBody @Validated email: SendEmailRequest
    ) : SendEmailRequest {
        return email
    }
}
```

and request class with nested classes:

```
class Request {
    @Nonnull
    @Valid
    val email: Letter? = null
}

class Letter {
    @Nonnull
    @Valid
    val receiver: EmailContact? = null

    @NotBlank
    val header: String = ""
    val plainText: String = ""
    val htmlContent: String = ""
}
```

Now I'm trying to send requests with Postman. The body of request is

```
{
    "email": {
        "header": ""
    }
}
```

The expected behavior is:

```
{
    "email.receiver": [
        "must not be null"
    ],
    "email.header": [
        "must not be blank"
    ]
}
```

The actual behavior (actual response) is:

```
{
    "email.header": [
        "must not be blank"
    ]
}
```

Why `@Nonnull` is not working?

Comment: Umm... my guess is because you're trying to use the wrong annotation. `jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull` is what you're looking for

Comment: You are right, changing to `jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull` fixed problem.